# Java method with @Inject annotation: False-positive for the rule "Unused "private" methods should be removed"?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, sonarqube

We are using Java 8 and Dependency Injection (GUICE).
Currently we have a false-positive Sonar issue, about unused method, although this method is invoked via reflection from GUICE Injector, due to Inject Annotation.

Affected code:

```
 @Inject
 private void setTransactionalCommandStack(TransactionalCommandStack transactionalCommandStack) {
   ...
}
```

SQ reports a violation of the rule squid:UnusedPrivateMethod

> Unused "private" methods should be removed

at this place and says

> Private method 'setTransactionalCommandStack' is never used

.

The Eclipse environment which also has a check for unused methods detects it correctly and only puts a warning if I have no @Inject annotation for the method.
The same I would expect in SonarQube.

I tested both Annotation javax.inject.Inject and com.google.inject.Inject. In both cases SonarQube reports that the method is unused.

SQ version: 5.3

Java plugin version: 3.14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been fixed in version `4.0` of the Java Analyzer, only compatible with SQ LTS `5.6`. See corresponding JIRA ticket [SONARJAVA-1179](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-1179)